# find directories

Tags: unix, scripting, grep

I have been trying to get to count all the empty folders in a certain directory. sub-directories excluded. i used the code below but i don't know how to define empty folders or folders that contain files.

```
echo "$(ls -l | egrep -l $1/* | wc -l)"
```

the $1 will be the user argument in the command line. example: ./script.sh ~/Desktop/backups/March2021.

Edit - im not allowed to use find command

Edit 2 - `ls -l * | awk '/total 0/{print last}{last=$0}' | wc -l` this script works but lists all folders even if the directory contains files and data or if the directory is empty.

Comment: Disallowing the use of the proper tool is a poor way to learn.

Comment: no my assignment won't allow the find command for some reason

Comment: As it is an assignment I only give some hints: I assume that you can ignore file and directory names that start with a dot and that you don't have file or directory names that contain newlines or other "problematic" characters. You can try to compare the output of `ls -1d */` *(a)* and `ls -1d */*` *(b)*. Empty directories should occur in *(a)* but not in *(b)*. You could strip the part after the last `/` from *(b)* and convert it to a pattern list for `grep` to display all non-matching lines from *(a)*. (I consider this approach as a workaround for stupid restrictions, not a good solution.)

Comment: ` echo "$(ls -1d $1/** | grep -e | ls -1d $1*/* )" `   this is what i ended up with. the problem is that $1*/* does or $1/** don't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
grep -v "." *
```

I mean the following: "." means any character (I'm not sure the syntax is correct), so basically you look for every file which not even contain any character.

Answer (score 1):

You should not parse `ls` (directories or file names with newlines), so this solution is only for the assignment:

```
ls -d */ */* | cut -d/ -f1 | sort | uniq -u | wc -l
```

Explanation:
`ls -d */` shows all directories. This is combined with `ls -d */*` which will also show contents in the directories.
The resulting output will show all directories.
Empty directories will be shown only once, so you want to look for unique lines.
With the `cut` you only see the name of the directory, not the files in the directory.
The `sort` could be skipped here, the `ls` will give sorted output. When you change the solution to `find` (next assignment?) the sort might be needed.
`uniq` can look for lines that occur once. The flag `-u` removes all lines that have duplicates, so it will show the unique lines in the output.

Comment: can you explain this please. @Walter A

Comment: Explanation added. You can see what happens when you only execute parts of the command.

Comment: do you think its possible to add a user argument instead of the `*/ or */*` like for example if the user writes `./script.sh ~/Desktop/backups/March2021` so that the script will run on the given directory rather than the current working directory.

Comment: usually the user input will be `$1` so my question is that if it is possible to work with something like `$1*/ and $1*/*`.

Comment: Sure. Try `cd "$1"; original_solution` when you don't want to change the `cut -d/ -f1`.
harder to understand is `ls -d $1/*/ "$1"/*/* -1 | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}' | uniq -u | wc -l`.